# How to remove noise from an audio file in python

Tags: python, audio, speech, librosa

I have an audio file recorded in a noisy environment and want to remove the noisy part before further processing can occur, the other approach I have used only reduce the volume of the audio file and another one that just only cleaned some part of the audio and render the audio as an incomplete speech,
Looking forward to another method of getting this done

I have use librosa and also ffmpeg but the result are not recommendable

Comment: What kind of noise is it?

Comment: Is it a single audio file (or a few)? In that case, I would recommend using a ready-made audio denoising tool. You can try the one in Audacity for example

Comment: a single audio file, i saw the one audacity, just wanted something i can create with python and eventually convert it to an endpoint

in this case the noise is coming from moving vehicle when recording the audio

Comment: Noise from moving vehicle. If it is a complex non-stationary sounds you may need something like https://github.com/Shb742/rnnoise_python

Comment: wasn't written in python

Comment: You can try https://pypi.org/project/denoiser/ - but it uses PyTorch, which is a lot of C/C++ code under the hood - like any decent DSP/ML library